# .NET Core published app displays only 500 error

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core app running on Ubuntu 16.04. It works fine when I navigate to the directory and run `dotnet run`. I am also able to set up the Nginx reverse proxy, as specified [on the .NET Core Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/linuxproduction#configure-a-reverse-proxy-server). However, when I do `dotnet publish` and then try using `dotnet SlogWeb.dll` from the publish directory(`SlogWeb/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.0/publish`), the server starts up without errors but it fails to display any logging information and navigating to the website produces a 500 error.

You can see [the full project on GitHub](https://github.com/GinBlades/Slog). The important bits are probably my project.json file:

```
// dependencies and tools
"publishOptions": {
    "include": [
        "wwwroot",
        "web.config",
        "appsettings.Production.json"
    ]
},

"scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "gulp build" ]
}
```

And the configure method of my Startup.cs file:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, DbSeeder dbSeeder) {
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();

    if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
    }

    if (env.IsProduction()) {
        app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions {
            ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
        });
    }

    // ...
```

If I navigate to `SlogWeb/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.0/publish` and run `dotnet SlogWeb.dll`, I get the standard startup message but then silence:

```
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: /home/shaun/sites/Slog/src/SlogWeb/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.0/publish
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

Please let me know if there is anything else I should post.

Comment: Do you receive error 500 from Nginx or from Kestrel? Run website without Nginx and see if you receive any result from Kestrel directly. It's very strange if Kestrel will return 500 error to you without any messages in log (unless you disabled logging - check your `Startup` for logging settings).

Comment: @Dmitry I added the logging methods I'm using and what I see from Kestrel when I try to run the published `.dll`.

Comment: Have you made sure that your views get published under publishOptions:include?

Comment: do you receive error 500 from `http://localhost:5000` (Kestrel only) or from `http://localhost:80` (Nginx+Kestrel)?

Comment: `localhost:5000`. I startup the server and see startup message in the console. But when I navigate to it from a browser, I get the 500 error and nothing is logged to the console.

Comment: So, your trouble does not related to Nginx and related only to publishing your app. App does not work when published. Your repo does not contains `appsettings.production.json`, and you do not publishing `appsettings.json` (`publishOptions` in projects.json). This may lead to zero logging, because you configure logging from configuration which does not contains `Logging` section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see nothing in console because your publish/logging configurations is wrong.

You have `appsettings.json` file, but you don't publish it (`publishOptions` in `projects.json`). You publish `appsettings.productions.json` which does not exist.

As result, you have no any `Logging` section in your configuration. This [may be] the reason you see nothing in console.

Comment: This in addition to @iikkoo's comment about publishing views solved my problem. The `appsettings.Production.json` file is intentially excluded from the repository because it contains the secret config I use user-secrets for in development. Once I added `appsettings.json` to the `publishOptions:include` array, the logging worked correctly and I was able to see the problem was missing Views.

Answer (score -2):

Did you install and configure nginx? https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/install/

example conf:

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

}

Comment: nginx configuration is totally irrelevant here.